# iOS App crashes when it's updated in the AppStore, but not when it's installed in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, app-store

I'm using CoreData in my app. When I modify an entity or attribute, upload it to the AppStore and try to update it, it crashes. I have to uninstall and download again. Is there a way to bypass this and that my update automatically deletes the outdated version and installs the latest version? How can I resolve this in the most user friendly and efficient way?

Comment: You need to do Core Data versioning for it. Check this - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

Comment: As others have mentioned, you need to set up Core Data versioning and migration, but, you can test this in Xcode, you don't need to go through TestFlight or the App Store. Just install an old version on your device (or simulator), and then run the new version in Xcode on top. That will give you the same results and will let you test the migration while debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new core data model and migration.

Please use the tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-migrations--cms-21844